# Getting a Type as an Interface to return from a function

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I have a function that returns an interface.

I want to avoid a bunch of IF ELSE and get the type via reflection.
So I pass in the namespace, typename and assemblyname as strings and construct the type OK.
However,  I'm stuck at how to return it as an interface.

My interface is names ILevel2.  The types I am returning all implement it so I hope the folllowing would work but no joy yet...

Could someone point me in the right direction.....

```
    string instanceReq = String.Format("{0}.{1}, {2}", nameSpace, typName, assseblyName);
    var myType = Type.GetType(instanceReq);
    ILevel2 myInterface = myType.GetInterface("ILevel2");

    return myInterface;
```

I get a compiler error on the line setting myInterface =.....

> Error 114 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to
>   'Level2Obligations.ILevel2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a
>   cast?)    D:\TFS\StockMaster_ECodes\StockMaster_ECode_Admin_MVC5\WebAPI\ECode_Web_Api\Models\ECodeLevel2Request.cs    103 35  ECode_Web_Api

Adding more detail......

In a mess at the moment but as you can see - i'm trying to be more generic rather than IF (namesapaceandType == "bghjbj")

```
private ILevel2 GetDLLInstance(string namespaceAndType)
{
    var assseblyName = "Level2_Mock_Api";
    var nameSpace = "Level2_Mock_Api";
    var typName = "MockAPI";

    string instanceReq = String.Format("{0}.{1}, {2}", nameSpace, typName, assseblyName);
    var myType = Type.GetType(instanceReq);
    var myInterface = (ILevel2)myType.GetInterface("ILevel2");

    return myInterface;

    if (namespaceAndType.ToUpper() == "LEVEL2_MOCK_API.MOCKAPI")
    {
        return new Level2_Mock_Api.MockAPI();
    }
    else......
```

In case anyone has this issue in future here is the function I have eneded up with...........

```
private ILevel2 GetDLLInstance(string AssemblyNamespaceAndType)
{
    //As the name suggests this should be the Assembly Namespace and Type seperated by fullstops and is case sensitve
    //eg Level2_Mock_Api.Level2_Mock_Api.MockAPI
    string[] apiDetails = AssemblyNamespaceAndType.Split('.');
    var assseblyName = apiDetails[0];
    var nameSpace = apiDetails[1];
    var typeName = apiDetails[2];
    string typeReq = String.Format("{0}.{1}, {2}", nameSpace, typeName, assseblyName);
    var myType = Type.GetType(typeReq);
    if (myType != null)
        return (ILevel2)Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

    return null;
}
```

So now, as and when I need to add new implementations, I just need to make sure they implement the interface and I'll be good to go ;)

Comment: It sounds like you need to construct an *instance* of the type... it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve at the moment. If you included a short but *complete* example (instead of a snippet) that would make it easier to help you

Comment: Aaaaah - I see Jon, I have the type, now create an instance of that type....
I'll see how I get on.

Comment: Well hopefully my answer will help on that front :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you just need to create an instance of the type and cast it to the interface that you're confident it implements:

```
return (ILevel2) Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

That will use the parameterless constructor, however - if you need to call a different constructor, you could call `myType.GetConstructors()`, or just call `Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Object[])` and let that pick the constructor to call.

Comment: Thanks.
Already rename instanceReq to typeReq ;)

Thanks again.  Very useful